# SKAction.animateWithTextures with dynamic timePerFrame

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like my hero to be able to change running speed dynamically, I am trying to figure out what i did wrong here:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation for `SKAction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:) you can see that the type for `timePerFrame` is an `NSTimeInterval` (a typealias for `Double`). Therefore you just need to change the type of `val` to `NSTimeInterval`:

```
private func run(val: NSTimeInterval) {
    // ...
}
```

---

You may also be interested in the [`speed` property on `SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/speed), which can be used to change the speed of any `SKAction`s a node is performing, whilst they're being performed.